# Created two spinners but selection is not working

Tags: android, listener, android-spinner

I'm new to android and I'm having some trouble. I created 2 spinners. The first one goes and fetches YEARS and populates the first spinner dynamically. Based on what year the user picks, the 2nd spinner goes off and fetches Car Makes (Ford, Honda etc.) for that specific year and dynamically updates the 2nd spinner. When I launch the app, the 1st spinner is populated correctly with the years, but when I select a year, the selection does not get selected. I have been reading around and I'm 90% sure all my code is correct but I think some of it is just in the wrong place. For example, should I be using the onCreate Method more? Should I be splitting up each spinner in different methods? Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or if you're extra nice, re-format it so it will work? Here is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

    final Spinner year=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_year);
    final Spinner make=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_make);

    final ArrayList<String> year_options = new ArrayList<String>();
    final ArrayList<String> make_options = new ArrayList<String>();


    /*
     * ASYNC TASK CLASSES
     */

    class populateYear extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, NodeList> {
        protected NodeList doInBackground(URL... urls) {
            NodeList yearList = null;
            try {
                DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = db.parse(urls[0].openStream());
                Element docEle = doc.getDocumentElement();

                yearList = docEle.getElementsByTagName("menuItem");


            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            return yearList;

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(NodeList yearList) {

            if (yearList != null && yearList.getLength() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < yearList.getLength(); i++) {
                    Node node = yearList.item(i);
                    if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                        Element e = (Element) node;
                        NodeList nodeList = e.getElementsByTagName("text");
                        year_options.add(nodeList.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());
                    }
                }
            } else {
                System.exit(1);
            }

        }
    }


    class populateMake extends AsyncTask<String, Void, NodeList> {
        protected NodeList doInBackground(String... strings) {
            NodeList makeList = null;
            try {
                DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                //Building a URL with "strings[0]" being equal to the year that we pass to the class.
                URL url = new URL("http://www.fueleconomy.gov/ws/rest/vehicle/menu/make?year=" + strings[0]);
                Document doc = db.parse(url.openStream());
                Element docEle = doc.getDocumentElement();

                makeList = docEle.getElementsByTagName("menuItem");


            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            return makeList;

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(NodeList makeList) {

            if (makeList != null && makeList.getLength() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < makeList.getLength(); i++) {
                    Node node = makeList.item(i);
                    if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                        Element e = (Element) node;
                        NodeList nodeList = e.getElementsByTagName("text");
                        make_options.add(nodeList.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());
                    }
                }
            } else {
                System.exit(1);
            }

        }
    }


    /*
     * END OF ASYNC TASK CLASSES
     */


    final ArrayAdapter<String> yearAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,year_options);

    //Filling the YEAR SPINNER
    URL xmlURL = null;
    try {
        xmlURL = new URL("http://www.fueleconomy.gov/ws/rest/vehicle/menu/year");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //Parse the XML and use the value by calling the AsyncTaskClass
    new populateYear().execute(xmlURL);

    //Setting the Year Adapter
    year.setAdapter(yearAdapter);

    final ArrayAdapter<String> makeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,make_options);
    //Disabling the MAKE spinner onLoad. Will be enabled later when user picks a year.
    make.setEnabled(false);
    //Setting the Make Adapter
    make.setAdapter(makeAdapter);  



    //Adding the listener for when someone selects a YEAR
    year.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {


        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            year.setSelection(position);
            String selectedYear=year_options.get(position).toString();




            resetMake(selectedYear);                               
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }

        public void resetMake(String selectedYear) {      
            //Clear the ArrayList belonging to MAKE so you can add new data based on the YEAR selection
            make_options.clear();
            new populateMake().execute(selectedYear);

            //Clear the makeAdapter and then add the new makes bases on the YEAR selection.
            makeAdapter.clear();
            for(int i=0; i < make_options.size(); i++) {
                makeAdapter.add(make_options.get(i));
            }
            makeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            make.setEnabled(true);
        }


}
```

Comment: I'm having trouble with what you want to happen so tell me if I have it right. You want to select a year from the 1st `Spinner` and have that populate the second `Spinner` with makes? If this is correct then tell me what happens, if anything, in the second `Spinner` after you select a year.

Comment: Also, you should get a `NPE` because these `final Spinner year=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_year);
    final Spinner make=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_make);` should be declared inside a method like `onCreate()`

Comment: Yes you are correct. The links are in the code that return XML which I parse and then put into the spinners. If I pick 1994 for a year, it will put 1994 into a url which will return all car makes for that year in XML. I then parse that and put the results into the 2nd spinner. And Yes! Declaring stuff in onCreate(); That's where my lack of android knowledge starts to show. If you could show where certain pieces of code go and why, I would really appreciate it! Do I need to split each spinner up into separate methods? I'm kind of lost

Comment: I don't mind helping with that...I just have to have a better understanding of what you are trying to do, what results you are expecting, and what you are getting before posting an answer

Comment: It seems your second `Spinner` just isn't getting populated, correct? Are you getting any errors while running this code? What is happening in your `Spinner`? No errors and not just getting repopulated?

Comment: The first spinner is getting populated fine. But when I select a year in the first spinner, it doesn't "select" my selection. And since it doesn't select it, the 2nd spinner doesn't get populated. It's supposed to hit the onItemSelected() when a year is selected and then hit the resetMake() method. In that method is where I populate the 2nd spinner.

Comment: Ok, I see what's going on. Give me a few and I will put together an answer that should help.

Comment: Thanks so much! Like I said, I'm pretty sure my code is fine, I'm just confused on the placement.

Comment: I have posted an answer. See if that helps. I may edit a little more but that should solve your problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32784/discussion-between-zack-and-codemagic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of an `AsyncTask` is for it to run asynchronously from the `UI` thread so the app can keep running. This means that when you start the task the rest of your code in your function will continue to run. Because of this, when you enter `public void resetMake(String selectedYear) {` your `AsyncTask` runs but so does the rest of the code in that function meaning your `Adapter` tries to populate before the new data has been downloaded.

There are a couple of ways to handle this. You could just move all of your code in that function after executing your task to `onPostExecute()` of that task.

```
protected void onPostExecute(NodeList makeList) {

        if (makeList != null && makeList.getLength() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < makeList.getLength(); i++) {
                Node node = makeList.item(i);
                if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element e = (Element) node;
                    NodeList nodeList = e.getElementsByTagName("text");
                    make_options.add(nodeList.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());
                }
            }
  //Clear the makeAdapter and then add the new makes bases on the YEAR selection.
        makeAdapter.clear();
        for(int i=0; i < make_options.size(); i++) {
            makeAdapter.add(make_options.get(i));
        }
        makeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        make.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            System.exit(1);
        }

    }
```

Doing this would leave your function with just

```
 public void resetMake(String selectedYear) {      
        //Clear the ArrayList belonging to MAKE so you can add new data based on the YEAR selection
        make_options.clear();
        new populateMake().execute(selectedYear);
```

So you could just move that to the `onItemSelected()` of your first `Spinner` and do away with this function.

**Note** I haven't checked this code for completeness so you may have syntax errors and need to move curly brackets and such around so it will compile.

**Additional Notes**

Typically you will initialize your `Views` in `onCreate()`, though you may declare them as member variables and you shouldn't usually need to make them `final`. This will also make your code more readable. So the beginning of your class may look something like this:

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Spinner year, make; // you can declare them here so you can use them anywhere in the Activity

    ArrayList<String> year_options = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> make_options = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        year = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_year);  // and initialize them here
        make=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_make);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks again for everything!